# Using cx_freeze with PyQT5 and Python 3 on MacOSX

Tags: macos, python-3.x, cx-freeze, pyqt5

I'm trying to use cx_freeze 4.3.3 on a MacOS running 10.9.2 on a very simple PyQt5 script with Python 3.3.

No errors are returned and the .app is output. However when running the .app from terminal I obtain the error:

```
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810
```

which according to Apple's documentation is "Unknown Error".

The very simple code I try to run (PyQt5app.py) is:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
form = QDialog()
form.show()
app.exec_()
```

The file setup.py is:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

base = None
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = 'Win32GUI'

options = {
    'build_exe': {
        'excludes': ['Tkinter']  # Sometimes a little finetuning is needed
    }
}

executables = [
    Executable('PyQt5app.py', base=base)
]

setup(name='PyQt5app',
      version='0.1',
      description='Sample PyQt5 GUI',
      executables=executables,
      options=options
      )
```

and when running I call:

```
sudo python cx_freeze bdist_mac
```

obtaining this log : http://pastebin.com/VBxyyBRn

with app returning error above.

So, reading around I see it might be a problem related to including qt files in the app (or at least this was the issue on PyQt4) so I try specifying the qt-menu-nib directory:

```
sudo python setup.py bdist_mac --qt-menu-nib=/Users/franco/Qt5.2.1/5.2.1/clang_64/plugins/platforms/
```

obtaining this log: http://pastebin.com/TpRdrSmT

and the same not working error.

If I run the app from PyQt5app.app/Contents/MacOS/PyQt5app I get a lot of bootstrap errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/cx_Freeze-4.3.3-py3.3-macosx-10.9-x86_64.egg/cx_Freeze/initscripts/Console.py", line 27, in <module>
    exec(code, m.__dict__)
  File "PyQt5app.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 1565, in _find_and_load
    return _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 1532, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    loader.load_module(name)
  File "ExtensionLoader_PyQt5_QtWidgets.py", line 22, in <module>
  File "ExtensionLoader_PyQt5_QtWidgets.py", line 14, in __bootstrap__
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 1565, in _find_and_load
    return _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 1532, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    loader.load_module(name)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 584, in _check_name_wrapper
    return method(self, name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 495, in set_package_wrapper
    module = fxn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 508, in set_loader_wrapper
    module = fxn(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 1132, in load_module
    fullname, self.path)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 313, in _call_with_frames_removed
    return f(*args, **kwds)
SystemError: initialization of sip raised unreported exception
```

Needless to say the script works fine when launching from terminal:

```
python PyQt5app.py
```

I most certainly am doing something wrong, so please, can anybody help me?

Answer (score 3):

So, after long fighting here is the issue: libzmq . 
I installed libzmq and specified the --qt-menu-nib option and the simple example above runs in both:

```
sudo python setup.py build
```

and

```
sudo python setup.py bdist_mac
```

Step by step instructions:

I used mac ports for most of my python33 packages so I sticked to it for the rest.
Libzmq is not available on macports but its dependencies are.
So:

1) install libtool, autoconf, automake:

```
sudo port install libtool
sudo port install autoconf
sudo port install automake
```

2) grab the latest version of libzmq from  https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq ( I downloaded the ZIP for sake of order ) and unzip/navigate to the folder

```
/libzmq-master
```

now the instructions provided in the INSTALL document in the folder are pretty clear, if you installed all the dependencies then you will be fine.
run:

```
sudo ./autogen.sh
sudo ./configure
sudo make
sudo make install
```

3) download the latest cx_freeze from https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/downloads then unzip/untar navigate to folder and run:

```
sudo python setup.py build
sudo python setup.py install
```

now when compiling code for MacOSX that uses Python3.3 and PyQt5 you can run:

```
sudo python setup.py build
```

then navigate in the build folder and run the program as:

```
./nameoftheprogram
```

once you made sure this work then build the app or dmg (as you prefer) with:

```
sudo python setup.py bdist_mac --qt-menu-nib=/Users/username/Qt5.2.1/5.2.1/clang_64/plugins/platforms/
```

where the path is the path to your Qt5 installation. If I don't use the --qt-menu-nib option the app crashes on startup whereas the build works fine.

Hope this will help someone in the future.

Comment: Hi HeoN this sounds like the exact step by step I'm looking for but excuse me, I'm beginner with this, could you please contact me by Twitter because I'm in trouble or maybe you could share another more detailed tutorial please? I'm @Lexynux on twitter, I promise not to butter you too many times. Thanks for all this info, I'm going to try right now!

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error and recompiling with the latest version of ZMQ (4.0.4) did not solve the issue.

However, by looking in the messages of the `/Applications/Utilities/Console.app` program, I could see that an extra command line option was given to my Python program. This command line option always started with `-psn_0_` followed by a number. Apparently psn stands for Process Serial Number (see: http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showthread.php?t=11978).

My program uses the `argparse` package to parse the command line arguments and exited with an error because it didn't recognized the -psn option. I now filter it out before parsing with `argparse` and this solved my problem.