# Building PyQT App for Macosx

Tags: python, macos, qt, pyqt

Hi I am trying to build one simple PyQt app for mac osx using cx_freeze, the building process completed without any error and it is creating Myapplication.app file. But When I am trying run it, it just crashesh. I tried to run that from terminal and found the following error

```
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for the file /Users/XXXXX/Desktop/untitled folder/pywork/cx_freeze/build/MyApplication.app
```

I have tried to follow some solution from here ([Using cx_freeze with PyQT5 and Python 3 on MacOSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23621130/using-cx-freeze-with-pyqt5-and-python-3-on-macosx))

I am running Mac OSX 10.9, Python 2.7, QT 4.8.

Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: Can you reduce the project code to get a minimal example showing the error? With this others can reproduce the problem.

Comment: It is very simple Hellow world GUI Application.